# Is there an event that fires when <img> is shown on page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

When I dynamically insert a img element in DOM, the load event is triggered when the image is loaded. Then I use $.width() and $.height() to get its size and properly layout it on page.

But lately when I use this method in a dialog, it fails because the dialog which contains the image is initially hidden. So when img's load event is fired, its width and height are all 0.

Is there an event that gets triggered when img is actually visible on a page?

Or if not, how can I reliably get img size when it is loaded in a browser?

Comment: hide the dialogue using fixed positioning off the screen rather than display none

Comment: As I know, you should try to predownload images, then get it's width and height, and only then images with size show it. First load images by JS, and only after this show it on page.